# C# Image.Clone to byte[] causes EDIT.COM to open on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, windows-xp

It appears that cloning a Image and converting it to a byte array is causing EDIT.COM to open up on Windows XP machines. This does not happen on a Windows 7 machine. The application is a C# .NET 2.0 application. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

Here is my Image conversion code:

```
        public static byte[] CovertImageToByteArray(Image imageToConvert)
    {
        imageToConvert.Clone() as Image;

        if(clone == null)
            return null;

        imageToConvert.Dispose();

        byte[] imageByteArray;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            clone.Save(ms, clone.RawFormat);
            imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return imageByteArray;
    }


    public static Image ConvertByteArrayToImage(byte[] imageByteArray,
                                                ImageFormat formatOfImage)
    {
        Image image;

        using (
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray, 0,
                                               imageByteArray.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.Length);
            image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        }

        return image;
    }
```

Thanks

Justin

Comment: Is it one particular image? The image may be malformed and contain exploit/shellcode.

Comment: No it appears to be any image. I will go test a few others on a couple different machines.

Comment: Image is type System.Drawing.Image

Comment: Doesnt matter what image or format. Happens on Windows XP and Windows 2000 Machines. I havent tried Vista, but it does NOT happen on Windows 7.

Comment: Probably because Win7 no longer has edit.com.  How do you save these images?  What is the filename extension?

Comment: The images are saved within a SQL Server database. They can originate from wherever as long as they are png, jpg, gif, or bmp.

Comment: That's really weird. I suggest you to find the responsible line in the code that you post using debugger with step over the code line by line. Then go deep into the subroutines of the responsible line, i am sure that will give you hints about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help without guessing here, so here we go:

Somewhere in your code you or an external library relies on/calls an external tool, called "edit.exe". Maybe, god forbid, even something triggered in the database. The programmer didn't care about the extension, wrote "edit foo.bar" in the Process.StartInfo.
Because of your PATH and the order of resolution (com before exe) this ends up calling edit.com on machines that come with it.

Well - this is really nothing but an artificial story, but I cannot imagine a way of launching any app with the code you've given. Try to be sure about the exact place where this happens. I doubt that it is the conversion/the code you showed.

Comment: This is the exactly the type of answer i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging it turns out to be something strange going on with a HyperLinkEdit from DevExpress. The Text value was set to "Edit". I renamed it to "Edet" and the issue went away. I will be reporting this to DevExpress for further evaluation.

Thanks everyone,

Justin